# Json String Decoding into different String Values

Tags: json

I have JsonArray like this

```
[
    {
        "id": "60",
        "variant_id": "0",
        "name": "Grape Tomato- 150gm",
        "category": "10",
        "content": "{\"calories\":\"50\",\"carbohydrate\":\"\",\"fat\":\"\",\"protein\":\"\"}",
        "variant_size": "",
        "types": "{\"ptype\":\"VG\"}",
        "price": "45 ",
        "discription": "<p>Grape tomatoes are hybrid tomatoes in smaller in size and sweet in taste. These are ideal to have especially in salads.</p>\n",
        "item_image": "userfile60.jpg",
        "graph_image": "graphfile60.png",
        "isVariant": "NO"
     },
```

and i am getting the response.
Now for "content" key for the above JsonArray is Coming in the string formate like this

```
{"calories":"50","carbohydrate":"","fat":"","protein":""}
```

How can i take these values into different strings so that i can use then to display or to use the value for pie chart
For example :

```
String calories = "value" 
String carbohydrate= "value"
Sting fat ="value"
String Protein="value"
```

from the above response .. i want to get the data in this pattern, please help.

Comment: What language are you using to decode the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, answer in Swift, using Codable protocol. Maybe someone gets happy.

```
struct YourModel: Codable {
    let id: String
    let variant_id: String
    let name: String
    let category: String
    let content: Content
    let variant_size: String
    let types: Types
    let price: String
    let discription: String
    let item_image: String
    let graph_image: String
    let isVariant: String

    struct Types: Codable {
        let ptype: String
    }

    struct Content: Codable {
        let calories: String
        let carbohydrate: String
        let fat: String
        let protein: String
    }
}

let jsonData = "Your JSON".data(using: .utf8)!
let yourModelArray = try! JSONDecoder().decode([YourModel].self, from: jsonData)
```